# What are the last $r-$ subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

**Problem:** Consider the $r-$ subsets of $\{1,2,3...,n\}$ in lexicographic order. What are the last $r+1$ $r-$subsets?

**My Attempt:** I know that the last element is $(n-r+1)(n-r+2)...n,$ but I am unable to go back to the previous element and so on. Any hints or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is exactly one subset whose smallest element is $n-r+1$, and that subset will be last.

The subsets listed immediately before that one will be the ones whose smallest element is $n-r$. Conveniently, there are exactly $r$ of those: there are $\binom{r}{r-1} = r$ ways to choose which $r-1$ elements of $\{n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\}$ they will include.

So that will be all $r+1$ last subsets. We can also describe them by saying that they're all formed by taking the $(r+1)$ element subset $\{n-r, n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\}$ and leaving one element out:
\begin{align}
  \{n-r, n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\} & \setminus \{n\} \\
  \{n-r, n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\} & \setminus \{n-1\} \\
  \{n-r, n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\} & \setminus \{n-2\} \\
    \vdots \\
  \{n-r, n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\} & \setminus \{n-r+1\} \\
  \{n-r, n-r+1, n-r+2, \dots, n-1, n\} & \setminus \{n-r\}
\end{align}

You can check that these are in lexicographic order, and that they are the only subsets with smallest element $n-r$ or $n-r+1$. So they will come after all the other subsets, whose smallest element is $n-r-1$ or less.